# vim syntax highlight not working (MacOs Ventura)

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, macos-ventura

I use vim as my text editor, and I want to make use of highlighted syntax. However, I cannot get it to work when I use the command “syntax on” in my ~/.vimrc file.

The strange thing is that it does the syntax is highlighted in the ~/.vimrc file itself, but not in other files.

When I use the command “syntax on” in my ~/.vimrc file, it does highlight the text in the ~/.vimrc file itself, but not in other files. If I provide other commands in the ~/.vimrc file they work: colorscheme wors, set number also works. So the ~/.vimrc file itself is actually used and works correctly, only the “syntax on” command does not work.

Anybody who can help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can we see the **full** output of `$ vim --version`.

Comment: Your question is not internally consistant. You say that syntax highlighting doesn't work but you also say that "colorscheme wors". So what can we do with this?

Comment: I tried “colorscheme blue” and it results in a blue background, with the yellow color text. However, syntax highlight is not working because the entire text has the same color. I will check the extact output of “vim —version” when I have access to my laptop

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: We will need the content of your `vimrc` as well, and a command-by-command description of what you are doing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. Beginners mistake I guess...

As mentioned the comments, in the `.vimrc` file syntax highlighting worked fine. In the files I made myself, I just opened a file without extension (i.e. `vim testfile`).

In a file without extension, the syntax highlighting does not work because vim does not know how to highlight the syntax. When I now for instance open a file `vim testfile.py` (with the Python extension), it works fine.

Thanks anyway for your comments!

Comment: Yes, I will accepted it as soon as it is allowed (within 8 hours apparently)